# How to use Mockito BDD to mock a Class<?> return type method?

Tags: mockito, bdd

I'm having trouble to use Mockito BDD to mock the method whose return type is Class<?>

I'm trying to use BDD to mock this method:

```
    public Class<?> getInterfaceClass() {
        if (this.interfaceClass == null) {
            try {
                this.interfaceClass = this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(this.interfaceType);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException var2) {
                throw new RuntimeException(var2);
            } catch (NullPointerException var3) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return this.interfaceClass;
    }
```

This is how I mocked:
`given(serviceFactoryBean.getInterfaceClass()).willReturn(Comparable.class);`

But I got this error: `Cannot resolve method 'willReturn(Class<Comparable>)'`

May I know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Should work. Is your `given` really `BDDMockito#given` or a different method? What is its return type? What happens when you try to save the return value of `given` in a variable; what is its type?

Comment: This is the package I imported: `import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;`
This is the method body: 
 
public static <T> BDDMyOngoingStubbing<T> given(T methodCall) {
        return new BDDOngoingStubbingImpl(Mockito.when(methodCall));
}

Comment: This is just a guess, but try `.willReturn((Class)Comparable.class)`